# Default CKAN 2.9 install on Pi not visible from network

Tags: python, networking, raspbian, ckan, opendata

I am trying to install CKAN on a raspberry pi using the instructions found [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html). The RPi is running the latest Raspberry Pi OS (w/desktop / January 11th 2021 / Kernel 5.4) All is successful and CKAN seems to function normally when viewed on the local machine, but any attempt to access CKAN from other machines on the network get Connection Refused. Is CKAN blocking requests from external machines by default, and if so how do I change this? Both jetty and solr are accessible from external machines, and I don't have a firewall in between these machines.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by passing a host and port variable when running the ckan server. Adding -H 0.0.0.0 to the run command enabled listening on all interfaces.